# breeze self.manager.getChanges() returns 0

Tags: entity, breeze, savechanges

I'm trying to modify an entity in breeze and call saveChanges(). But the entitiesToSave in my breeze manager is 0. I'm not sure what I do wrong.

Here's how I retrieve the data through the controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [CustomAuthorize(Claims = "permission:CanViewLocationAttributes")]
    public Location GetLocationById(int clientId, int locationId)
    {
           //returns a single location object
    }
```

Then I display the properties of the location object, modify it and try to change as follows:

```
        function saveLocationSettings(clientId) {
        var self = this;
        var saveOptions = this.manager.saveOptions.using({ resourceName: "SaveLocationSettings",  allowConcurrentSaves: true });
        var entitiesToSave = self.manager.getChanges();
        return self.manager.saveChanges(entitiesToSave, saveOptions).then(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);
    }
```

Here when I inspect the entitiesToSave, it's 0. The changed entity is not included.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the entity that your are changing is in the same EntityManager as the one that you are save? Also remember that if you 'set' an entity's property to its current value then breeze will ignore the change.

An easy way to confirm both of these is to check the 'entityAspect.entityState' of the Entity after you have changed it ( it should be 'Modified') and then check the 'entityAspect.entityManager' to see if it is the same EntityManager that you plan to save.

Comment: could you please tell me how you can check this?